# Using Python to count if row contains this and that, then make a heat map(?unsure if this is the correct term) of the results

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, statistics, seaborn

My data looks like this

```
     cat1     cat2    cat3    cat4
a      0        1       1      0 
b      1        0       0      0
c      0        0       1      1 
d      0        1       1      1
```

I want to end up with something like this to assess the relationship between categories (is heat map the correct term?

```
      cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4
cat1    1      0       0       0
cat2    0      2       2       1
cat3    0      2       3       2
cat4    0      1       2       2
```

So I think I want to do something similar to count if contains cat1 and cat 2, count if contains cat 1 and cat 3 etc etc.

Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

Comment: you're not actually giving any example on how you want your data to be processed ... explain at least in words what you want the output to look depending on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`numpy.inner`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html):

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.inner(df.T, df.T), 
             index=df.columns,
             columns=df.columns)

      cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4
cat1     1     0     0     0
cat2     0     2     2     1
cat3     0     2     3     2
cat4     0     1     2     2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`matrix multiplication - dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by transpose `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.T.dot(df)
print (df)
     cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4
cat1     1     0     0     0
cat2     0     2     2     1
cat3     0     2     3     2
cat4     0     1     2     2
```